# Best way to combined hibernate search queries on different indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

We have the following situation

Given the following two entities

```
@Indexed
@Spatial(spatialMode = SpatialMode.HASH)
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
Address{

    @Field
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Field
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "town_city")
    private String townCity;

    @Field
    @Longitude
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "x_coord")
    private Double xCoord;

    @Field
    @Latitude
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "y_coord")
    private Double yCoord;

}
```

And

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
Person{

    @Field
    @Column(name = "weight")
    private Double weight;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;


    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = 
    org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinTable(name = "person_address",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")})
    private Set<Address> addressSet = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Getters and Setters rest of the fields omitted

We want to return in our search results as an example people within a 5KM radius of a given position who are also within an age range.

So

```
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession());
        this.queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class)
            .overridesForField("identifiers.identifier_edge", "identifier_query_analyzer")
            .get();
        this.bool = queryBuilder.bool();


            LocalDateTime lowerLocalDateTime = localDateTime.withYear(localDateTime.getYear() - upperAge);
            lowerDate = Date.from(lowerLocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

            LocalDateTime upperLocalDateTime = localDateTime.withYear(localDateTime.getYear() - lowerAge);
            upperDate = Date.from(upperLocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            bool.must(getQueryBuilder().range().onField("datesOfBirth.dateOfBirth").from(lowerDate).to(upperDate).createQuery());
```

which will give us people within the relevant age range

We have a separte query to get the address id's within a radius around a given point

```
public Set<Integer> getSpatialAddressResults(SpatialSearchCommand spatialSearchCommand) {

FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession());
    this.userSearchPreference = userSearchPreference;
    this.queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Address.class)
            .get();
    this.bool = queryBuilder.bool();

    Set<Integer> addressIdSet = new HashSet<>();

    bool.must(getQueryBuilder().spatial()
            .within(spatialSearchCommand.getRadius(), Unit.KM).ofLatitude
                    (spatialSearchCommand.getLat()).andLongitude(spatialSearchCommand.getLng()).createQuery());


    FullTextQuery fullTextQuery =
            fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(bool.createQuery(), Address.class)
                    .setProjection("addressId")
                    .initializeObjectsWith(ObjectLookupMethod.SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE,
                            DatabaseRetrievalMethod.QUERY);

    List results = fullTextQuery.list();
    for (Object result : results) {
        Object[] arrayResult = (Object[]) result;
        addressIdSet.add(((Integer) arrayResult[0]));
    }

    if (addressIdSet.size() == 0) {
        addressIdSet.add(-1);
    }


    return addressIdSet;

}
```

Which we use like below (in reality these are done in separate classes but for simplicity I have just shown the relevant code

```
Set<Integer> localAddressIds = getSpatialAddressResults(new SpatialSearchCommand(userSearchPreference.getRadius(), userSearchPreference.getLat(), userSearchPreference.getLng()));

if(localAddressIds.size() > 0){
        BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> localSquQueryBool = getQueryBuilder().bool();

        for (Integer localAddressId : localAddressIds) {
            localSquQueryBool.should(getQueryBuilder().keyword().onField("currentLocation.address.indexId").matching(localAddressId).createQuery());

            if(!personSearchCommand.getCurrentOnly()){
                localSquQueryBool.should(getQueryBuilder().keyword().onField("locations.address.indexId").matching(localAddressId).createQuery());
            }

        }

        bool.must(localSquQueryBool.createQuery());
    }
```

The problem is there can be a huge amount of addresses returned which results in a BooleanQueryTooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024

The question really is what is the best way to combined queries on two different indexed entities to avoid problems like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you are trying to implement a join operation. As you can see, there are technical challenges to joins which are not easily solved on the client side.

Generally, the recommended approach in Elasticsearch and Lucene is to avoid joins when you can. Instead, you will de-normalize your schema: within the document representing each person, embed a copy of every address. Then you will be able to express all your constraints in a single query targeting the `person` index.
This is done by annotating the `addresses` property in `Person` with `@IndexedEmbedded`.

Now, as you can imagine, this de-normalization comes at a cost: whenever an address is changed, Hibernate Search has to update the relevant person.
To that end, you will need to add a `List<Person>` property to your `Address` class and annotate it with `@ContainedIn` in order for Hibernate Search to be able to fetch the persons to reindex whenever an address is modified.

In short, change your model to this:

```java
//@Indexed // No longer needed
@Spatial(spatialMode = SpatialMode.HASH, name = "location") // Give a name to the spatial field
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
Address {
    // Add this
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "addressSet")
    @ContainedIn
    private Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<>();

    @Field
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Field
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "town_city")
    private String townCity;

    //@Field// This is not necessary
    @Longitude
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "x_coord")
    private Double xCoord;

    //@Field// This is not necessary
    @Latitude
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "y_coord")
    private Double yCoord;

}
```

```java
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
Person{

    @Field
    @Column(name = "weight")
    private Double weight;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;


    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = 
    org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinTable(name = "person_address",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")})
    @IndexedEmbedded // Add this
    private Set<Address> addressSet = new HashSet<>();

    @Transient
    @IndexedEmbedded // Also add this
    public Address getCurrentAddress() {
         // This was missing in your schema, I suppose it's a getter that picks the current address from addressSet?
    }

}
```

Then reindex. Your `Person` documents will now have two new fields: `addressSet.location` and `currentAddress.location`.

Then write your query like this:

```java
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession());
        this.queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class)
            .overridesForField("identifiers.identifier_edge", "identifier_query_analyzer")
            .get();
        this.bool = queryBuilder.bool();


            LocalDateTime lowerLocalDateTime = localDateTime.withYear(localDateTime.getYear() - upperAge);
            lowerDate = Date.from(lowerLocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

            LocalDateTime upperLocalDateTime = localDateTime.withYear(localDateTime.getYear() - lowerAge);
            upperDate = Date.from(upperLocalDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            bool.must(getQueryBuilder().range().onField("datesOfBirth.dateOfBirth").from(lowerDate).to(upperDate).createQuery());


SpatialSearchCommand spatialSearchCommand = new SpatialSearchCommand(userSearchPreference.getRadius(), userSearchPreference.getLat(), userSearchPreference.getLng());

// The magic happens below
BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> localSquQueryBool = getQueryBuilder().bool();

localSquQueryBool.should(getQueryBuilder().spatial()
        .onField("currentAddress.location")
        .within(spatialSearchCommand.getRadius(), Unit.KM)
        .ofLatitude(spatialSearchCommand.getLat())
        .andLongitude(spatialSearchCommand.getLng())
        .createQuery());

if(!personSearchCommand.getCurrentOnly()) {
    localSquQueryBool.should(getQueryBuilder().spatial()
            .onField("addressSet.location")
            .within(spatialSearchCommand.getRadius(), Unit.KM)
            .ofLatitude(spatialSearchCommand.getLat())
            .andLongitude(spatialSearchCommand.getLng())
            .createQuery());
}

bool.must(localSquQueryBool.createQuery());
```

Comment: Thanks yrodiere I had tried with the IndexEmbedded on the Address previously but was not sure how to reference it in the query. I think giving the spatial a name as in your example and reference it as you have shown should work. Will try it later

Comment: Thanks yrodiere it worked doing it that way. The only thing I needed to add was the of="spatial_name" to the Latitude and Longitude annotations.